# Need help on figuring out what I did wrong in this Inversions algorithm (based on merge sort)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

The objective is to find the number of inversions in an array of integers. For example,

> given : (1,3,5,2,4,6)
>
> the inversions are : (3,2) , (5,4) , (5,2).

That is, a total of three inversions. The O(n^2) solution requires two for loops but takes too long for a large input array. Since merge sort takes O(n(log(n))) time, it would make sense to implement it in this case.

By the divide & conquer method, we can achieve O(n(log(n))). The solution would be the sum of the inversions taken. The inversions are as follows (for an input array of size 'n'):

> left inversion if i,j <= n/2
>
> right inversion if i,j > n/2
>
> split inversion if i <= n/2 < j

Note:Split inversions are done when arr[i] > arr[j] and i < j.

On the basis of the above claims, this is the following algorithm I wrote (in which I first wrote that of merge sort, then tweaked it accordingly to return the number of inversions) for which I am attaining a wrong output. I'm unable to figure out where I went wrong.

(Please ask for additional information if required. I've been stuck on this for a while).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int merge(vector <int> & arr, int l, int m , int r)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int count = 0;
    int n1, n2;

    n1=m-l+1;
    n2=r-m;

    //temporary arrays to store the elements.

    int L[n1];
    int R[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        L[i]=arr[l+i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
    {
        R[j]=arr[m+1+j];
    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=l;

    while(i<n1 && j<n2)
    {
        if (L[i]<R[j])
        {
            arr[k]=L[i];
            i++;
        }

        else
        {
            arr[k]=R[j];
            j++;
            count=count+(m-i);
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i<n1)
    {
        arr[k]=L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j<n2)
    {
        arr[k]=R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    return count;
}

int mergeSort(vector <int> & arr, int l, int r)
{
    int m;
    int count=0;

    /*
     if (l<r)

     {

     m=l+(r-l)/2;



     mergeSort(arr, l, m);//used to recursively sort the left half of the array

     mergeSort(arr,m+1,r);//used to recursively sort the right half of the array

     merge(arr,l,m,r);//merges both arrays together.

     }
     */


    if(l<r)
    {

        m = (l + r) / 2;

        count =

        (mergeSort(arr, l, m) +

         mergeSort(arr, m+1, r) +

         merge(arr, l, m, r));

        return count;

    }

    else

        return 0;

}


void printArray(vector <int> A, int size)

{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)

    {
        cout<<A[i]<< " ";
    }

    cout<<endl;

}

int main()

{

    int n;

    cin>>n;

    //int arr[n];

    vector<int> arr(n);

    int i;


    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {

        cin>>arr[i];

    }
    /*
     cout<<"the given array is : "<<endl;
     printArray(arr, n);
     */        
    cout<<"the number of inversions are : "<<endl;
    cout<< mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1) <<endl;
    /*        
     cout<<"the sorted array is : "<<endl;
     printArray(arr, n);
     */      
    return 0;

}
```

> Test cases:
>
> **Case-1**
>
> Input:
>
> (for n = 6)
>
> 1 3 5 2 4 6
>
> Expected Output:
>   3
>
> Attained Output:
>   1
>
> **Case-2**
>
> Input:
>
> (for n = 15)
>
> 9 12 3 1 6 8 2 5 14 13 11 7 10 4 0
>
> Expected Output:
>   56
>
> Attained Output:
>   125

Comment: Having a newline between groups of code is good and increases readability. Having *to much* newlines between groups of code, or even between lines, make the code harder to read. Please edit your question to remove some of the extra newlines in the code.

Comment: Does that solve the issue? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, but it will make the code much more readable so more people will actually stop and read the code instead of just skipping your question. Also, you have tried to actually debug the program yourself? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line (with a small array) to see that it does what you think it does? I know it's hard with recursive code but it's still something that a programmer needs to learn and practice on. Also, for some input, what is the expected and actual output?

Comment: Finally, [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of the C++ language, some compilers have it as an extension of the actual C++ language. If you want a variable-length array you should use `std::vector` instead. Note that none of this will solve your problem, not by themselves. But using e.g. `std::vector` will make the code more robust, readability helps not only us but yourself too, and debugging will give you greater understanding of what really happens in the code with real data.

Comment: Added a few test cases. I've tried debugging it by understanding what each loop and function does, I'm posting this question as a last resort. I'll continue my attempt but if someone finds a solution before I do, it'd be of great help. Would it help to use vectors? The compilers (dev c++, xcode, codeblocks) I've used support variable length arrays and I am familiar with them which is the reason why they are used.  @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @RohanB -- Stay away from the variable length arrays and use `std::vector` instead.  The reason is that the VLA's do **not** help you at all in solving boundary issues, while `std::vector` does with the usage of `at()`.  VLA's are the scourge of the beginner programmer.  There have been numerous questions asked on SO where the poster uses VLA's, and can't understand why the program doesn't work.  Replacing the VLA's with `std::vector` along with usage of `vector::at()` many times *instantly* gets to why the program doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in calculation of number of inversions that we get on each step. Lets take a look on merging: 
We have two arrays L and R, and on each iteration we look on first numbers in each array (coz they are already sorted):

1). L[i] <= R[j]. That means that L[i] don't create new inversion with some remaining element from R.

2). L[i] > R[j]. That means that R[j] will create inversion with L[i], L[i + 1], L[i + 2], ..., L[n1 - 1]. From what I see your bug is in **count**  calculation. You add *(m - i)* instead of *(n1 - i)*. 
One more bug that I see is in type of count. If you assume size to be quite big (~10^5) you need some bigger type to store your value.

Hopefully that helps.